# Checking if a hash table contains a value without knowledge of the key?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable

Is there an efficient way to search a hash table for a value without knowing the key that was used to store it? 
I can’t seem to think of anything other than creating a separate hash table that stores keys as the value and the values are the keys.

Comment: If the value is also unique, then you should definitely use a `BiMap`. That's a Guava interface.

Comment: u want to check that particular value exist in map rght ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any additional data structure, you'll have to loop through the entire hash table to find the value. As a hash table is indexed purely by the hash of the **key**, there's no efficient way to find some **value**.

If your hash table is stored as an array of linked-lists (i.e. [separate chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining)), as hash tables typically are, you simply need two (nested) loops - one for the array, and one for the linked-list at some given index. (If your hash table uses [open addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing), i.e. an array of elements, you simply need a single loop).

If you're allowed an additional data structure, then yes, creating a separate hash table of value to key would be a good idea.

Comment: thanks. that’s what i assumed. is it more efficient to maintain two hash tables or to occasionally do a blanket search throughout the entire list?

Comment: It's really going to depend how often you're doing this search. Searching the entire collection is going to take quite a while, but maintaining 2 hash tables comes with a small overhead for each operation. If you're rarely searching by value, one hash table is fine. The exact turning point would be something to benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

The `containsValue(Object value)` method is used to check if this map maps one or more keys to the specified value.

```
      Hashtable htable = new Hashtable();

      htable.put(1, "A");
      htable.put(2, "B");
      boolean isavailable=htable.containsValue("A");

      // display search result
      System.out.println("Hash table contains value 'A': "+isavailable);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use that method. I’m tasked with rebuilding the hash table class from scratch. Is there a way to see how that method was written though?

Comment: sry cant understand the pblm.Can u explain again

Comment: The project i’m working on doesn’t allow me to import any java.utils. The point is to have us recreate the HashTable data structure from scratch. I was wondering if there was a way to look at the code for the containsValue() method to give me insight into how to build it myself.

Comment: ohkk understand.u mean to say that u need to check that value exist in map or not without using any java method.You need to write from scratch

Comment: All the pubilc Sun/Oracle source code is freely available in src.zip; if it's not in your jdk directory, you can get it [from Oracle](http://www.java.net/download/openjdk/jdk7/promoted/b147/openjdk-7-fcs-src-b147-27_jun_2011.zip).  If you want the private classes too, [there's a project on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdk7src/).